# Geometry Node - only modify faces with specific material

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

(Blender 3.4)

I have a fairly standard node group which distributes instances of a second object onto the target object. I want that node group to only affect faces that use a specific material. I've seen a couple of examples of this using the material index, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Is this possible in 3.4?

[image: top level]
[image: combining two sub-groups]
[image: actual work]

This is the object I'm starting with:
[image]
I want the darker green patches on the top and bottom to be affected by the geo nodes.

And this is what I get:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can make a *Selection* for the faces with the relevant material using a `Material Index` > `Compare`—*Equal* setup like this:

[image]

Comment: That's almost exactly what I have (added shots of my geo nodes)

Comment: @cleek And it doesn't work? Have you edited your question? I don't see any screenshots.

Comment: Sorry. took a second.

Comment: @cleek As you can see, it does work in my setup, so it must be something else that's messing things up. `Distribute Poinst on Faces` uses the *Face Corner* domain (not *Face*) so that might be producing unexpected results depending on the mesh, for instance. Hard to say without seeing the rest. Can you share your file (a simplified version if possible) on blend-exchange.com so we can take a look?

Comment: it looks like Mesh To Points works to select the material. Problem is that the material itself comes out completely stretched (look like the 'after' picture, but with my objects on top). i want to preserve the original textures.

Comment: @cleek Like I said, it's hard to say something when we can't see the whole setup—why would distributing points stretch a material? If you can share your file, we could take a look.

Comment: Ah... looks like my problem was in the first geo node sub-group. I don't need to re-combine the input geometry with the instantiated objects at that level, too. Just doing it in the top-level group is enough. So, your answer works. Thanks!